# Exculding multiple Nodes RVest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping newspaper articles and am struggling to figure out how to exclude more than one node. The R help says that `:not()` accepts a sequence of simple selectors. I tried the following

```
zeit_url <- read.html("http://www.zeit.de/wissen/gesundheit/2017-09/aids-hiv-neuinfektionen-europa-virus-gesundheit")

article <- zeit_url %>%
    html_nodes('.article-page>:not(.ad-container, .cardstack)') %>%
    html_text()
```

It does not work to separate the two nodes with a comma. Any suggestions how to correctly specify the sequence of selectors in `:not()`?

I have spent a lot of time searching for an answer, but I am new to R (and HTML), so I appreciate your patience if this is something obvious.

Comment: Right now your code is missing closing quotes and parentheses, and there is no class on that page called `article-age`, so it's unclear what you're trying to get.

Comment: Sorry for this, I corrected it in my code!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rvest)
zeit_url <- read_html("http://www.zeit.de/wissen/gesundheit/2017-
            09/aids-hiv-neuinfektionen-europa-virus-gesundheit")

article <- zeit_url %>%
           html_nodes(".article-page>:not(.ad-container):not(.cardstack)") %>%
           html_text()
```

Comment: Glad to help. You were close. Accept answer if this works for you.